# Extact the first item from each list and place in a new list then second item in second list and so forth python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list of names called zones

such as

```
Zones = ['Zone_A','Zone_B']
```

I also have a list of lists, which are series of directory paths which I combined from two separate lists as follows

```
Image_1_Path = ['Zone_A_first_Image','Zone_B_First_Image']
Image_2_Path = ['Zone_A_second_Image','Zone_B_second_Image']


List_of_List = [ZoneA_Path,ZoneB_Path]
```

I would like to take the first image path from within my list of list and place in a list called Zone_A and then second path and place in a list called Zone_B.  My actual data set is much bigger.

I would like the end results to be like

```
Zone_A = [Zone_A_first_Image, Zone_A_Second_Image]
Zone_B = [Zone_B_first_Image, Zone_B_Second_Image]
```

I have the following to make a new list from my zone names

```
for x in Zones:
       globals()[x] = []
```

which creates a series of empty lists, however, I am unsure how to bring everything together.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `Zone_A, Zone_B = zip(Image_1_Path, Image_2_Path)`

Comment: @IainShelvington unfortunately that did not work, and returns the following error ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2). I think the zip function will also return a tuple? I hoping for a list as the final outcomes

Comment: ZIP should work. If you have code we can run at our end, we can edit and show how it works

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is to create a dict from data and access 'Zones' by the dict key.

```
Zones = ['Zone_A', 'Zone_B']

Image_1_Path = ['Zone_A_first_Image', 'Zone_B_First_Image']
Image_2_Path = ['Zone_A_second_Image', 'Zone_B_second_Image']

Zones_Paths = dict(zip(Zones, [list(_) for _ in zip(Image_1_Path, Image_2_Path)]))

print(Zones_Paths['Zone_A'])
# or
print(Zones_Paths[Zones[0])
```

Prints

```
['Zone_A_first_Image', 'Zone_A_second_Image']
```